# PHP -> XPath with conditions

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a way to execute a xpath expression on a certain condition:

Here is the code I have:

```
<table>
    <table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <table>
                  <tr align="center" valign="top">
                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
                      <img alt="WorkInstruction_Icon" src=".\I_WI_Text.png"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <p>
                          <span>GEHAEUSE re einsetzen</span>
                       </p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left">
                      <a href=".\SCR_27Aug2013_101146_002.jpg">
                        <img src=".\SCR_27Aug2013_101146_002.jpg" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
             </td>
          </tr> 
       </thead>
    </table>
    <!-- MORE TABLES MY XPath has to evaluate -->
</table
```

I want my XPath-Query/Skript to do the following:

Check the alt-Attribute of the first img-tag of this table and if it contains WorkInstruction, so make an Array-Entry:

```
Array(

[0] => WorkInstruction Gehaeuse re einsetzen, 

[1] => WorkInstruction SCR_27Aug2013_101146_002.jpg)

)
```

The parts "Gehaeuse re einsetzen" and "SCR_27Aug2013" come from the span-Tag and the a-Tag.

It is not necessary that the array looks exactly this way. It is only important that I can identify the entries "Gehaeuse re einsetzen" and others as WorkInstructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$result = array();
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//table[tr[1]/td[1]/img[1][contains(@alt, "WorkInstruction")]]');
foreach ($nodes as $tableNode) {
  $result[] = array(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(tr[1]/td[2])', $tableNode),
    $xpath->evaluate('string(tr[2]/td[1]/a/@href)', $tableNode)
  );
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) "GEHAEUSE re einsetzen"
    [1]=>
    string(30) ".\SCR_27Aug2013_101146_002.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: thx, ThomasWeinert, for your help! I solved my problem using another way, but your code gave me the necessary hint! It is about the contextNodes you can use in XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by myself to solve my problem, but the code ThomasWeinert provided gave me the hint. It is about the contextNodes you can use in XPath:

```
function loadAndParse($link){
    //Parser die 3. Baut auf die Icons auf!

    //xpath-Dokument erstellen
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc -> loadHTMLFile($link);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $stepInfo = array();

    $first = $xpath->query('/html/body/table[last()]');
    $second = $xpath->query('thead/tr/td/table', $first->item(0));

    foreach ($second as $sectab) {
        $secdata = $xpath->query('tr/td/img/@alt', $sectab);

        if(preg_match("/WorkInstruction/", $secdata->item(0)->nodeValue)){
            $nodeList = $xpath->query('tr/*[text()] | tr/td//a/@href', $sectab);
            $length = $nodeList->length;
            for($j=0; $j<$length; $j++){
                $workIns[] = trim($nodeList->item($j)->nodeValue);
                $stepInfo["workIns"] = $workIns;
            }
        }
        if(preg_match("/DataCollect/", $secdata->item(0)->nodeValue)){
            $nodeList = $xpath->query('tr/*[text()]', $sectab);
            $length = $nodeList->length;
            for($j=0; $j<$length; $j++){
                $dataCol[] = trim($nodeList->item($j)->nodeValue);
                $stepInfo["dataCol"] = $dataCol;
            }
        }
        if(preg_match("/SIGN-OFF/", $secdata->item(0)->nodeValue)){
            $nodeList = $xpath->query('tr/*[text()]', $sectab);
            $length = $nodeList->length;
            for($j=0; $j<$length; $j++){
                $signOff[] = trim($nodeList->item($j)->nodeValue);
                $stepInfo["signOff"] = $signOff;
            }
        }
        if(preg_match("/ALERT/", $secdata->item(0)->nodeValue)){
            $nodeList = $xpath->query('tr/*[text()]', $sectab);
            $length = $nodeList->length;
            for($j=0; $j<$length; $j++){
                $warning[] = trim($nodeList->item($j)->nodeValue);
                $stepInfo["warning"] = $warning;
            }
        }
    }
    return $stepInfo;
}
```

Now you can put the gained data, wich is saved in their own array, in any kind of multidimensional array.